# I want catch all Exception logs for AOP with best performance

Tags: performance, spring, aop

I heaard that spring AOP is slower 30 times than aspectj.

So, I insert below code in the spring context xml.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

so, is aspectj applied to?

plz let me know and any idea that can substitute aop for better performance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

Just enables @AspectJ annotation support .The AOP runtime is still pure Spring AOP . See the following from spring [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj).

```
 @AspectJ refers to a style of declaring aspects as regular Java classes annotated with 
 Java 5 annotations. The @AspectJ style was introduced by the AspectJ project as part of 
 the AspectJ 5 release. Spring 2.0 interprets the same annotations as AspectJ 5, using a 
 library supplied by AspectJ for pointcut parsing and matching. The AOP runtime is still 
 pure Spring AOP though, and there is no dependency on the AspectJ compiler or weaver.
```

If you want to use Aspectj compiler/weaver , check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) .